# Why am I unable to skip a transaction in SQL Server 2017 transactional replication using the sp_setsubscriptionxactseqno stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2017, transactional-replication

I have a transaction number of a transaction that is throwing the following error:

```
Command attempted: if @@trancount > 0 rollback tran (Transaction sequence number: 0x00036322000B2628000100000000, Command ID: 1)

Error messages: The row was not found at the Subscriber when applying the replicated (null) command for Table '(null)' with Primary Key(s): (null) (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 20598) Get help: http://help/20598 The row was not found at the Subscriber when applying the replicated (null) command for Table '(null)' with Primary Key(s): (null) (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 20598) Get help: http://help/20598
```

When I execute the following:

```
sp_setsubscriptionxactseqno @publisher = '<publisher>'  
        , @publisher_db = '<publisher_db>'  
        , @publication = 'ALL'  
        , @xact_seqno = 0x00036322000B2628000100000000
```

in order to skip the offending transaction and then try to sync up the subscription, it doesn't skip the transaction, instead it keeps throwing the same error. When I execute the following:

```
USE distribution 
GO

DECLARE @PublisherServer  VARCHAR(50), 
        @PublicationDB    VARCHAR(50), 
        @SubscriberServer VARCHAR(50), 
        @SubscriberDB     VARCHAR(50), 
        @PublicationName  VARCHAR(50) 

SET @PublisherServer = '<Publisher Server>' 
SET @PublicationDB = '<Publication DB>' 
SET @SubscriberServer = '<Subscriber Server>' 
SET @SubscriberDB = '<Subscriber DB>' 
SET @PublicationName = '<Publication Name>' 

EXEC Sp_helpsubscriptionerrors 
  @PublisherServer, 
  @PublicationDB, 
  @PublicationName, 
  @SubscriberServer, 
  @SubscriberDB
```

I get 1,860 rows back all being:

```
id  time    error_type_id   source_type_id  source_name error_code  error_text  xact_seqno  command_id  session_id
23326   2020-07-15 15:52:27.640 0   0   MSSQL_ENG   20598   The row was not found at the Subscriber when applying the replicated (null) command for Table '(null)' with Primary Key(s): (null)  0x00036322000B2628000100000000  1   0
23326   2020-07-15 15:52:27.640 0   1   MSSQL_ENG       if @@trancount > 0 rollback tran    0x00036322000B2628000100000000  1   0
23326   2020-07-15 15:52:27.640 0   0   MSSQL_ENG   20598   The row was not found at the Subscriber when applying the replicated (null) command for Table '(null)' with Primary Key(s): (null)  0x00036322000B2628000100000000  1   0
23322   2020-07-15 15:50:09.100 0   1   MSSQL_ENG       if @@trancount > 0 rollback tran    0x00036322000B2628000100000000  1   0
23322   2020-07-15 15:50:09.100 0   0   MSSQL_ENG   20598   The row was not found at the Subscriber when applying the replicated (null) command for Table '(null)' with Primary Key(s): (null)  0x00036322000B2628000100000000  1   0
23322   2020-07-15 15:50:09.083 0   0   MSSQL_ENG   20598   The row was not found at the Subscriber when applying the replicated (null) command for Table '(null)' with Primary Key(s): (null)  0x00036322000B2628000100000000  1   0
23318   2020-07-15 15:47:45.423 0   0   MSSQL_ENG   20598   The row was not found at the Subscriber when applying the replicated (null) command for Table '(null)' with Primary Key(s): (null)  0x00036322000B2628000100000000  1   0
```

Why am I unable to skip that transaction? What am I missing?

EDIT:

I have tried to re-initialize the subscription, but it won't re-initialize. I manually attempt to start the 'Snapshot Agent' job from the 'Agents' tab and receive the following:

```
Status: Completed
Job: Snapshot Agent
Last Start Time: 7/16/2020 7:07:43 AM
Duration: 00:00:01
Last Action: [0%] A snapshot was not generated because no subscriptions needed initialization.
```

I marked two subscriptions for re-initialization and received the above. Below is a screenshot of the subscription listing:

[image: Subscription listing. The two in question are highlighted.]

But, even when I try to manually start the snapshot job, I receive the following:

[image: Job names and running values.]

Comment: The quickest solution may be to just reinitialize things by running the snapshot agent.  Is there a reason that would be impractical?

Comment: I will try that and let you know how it goes.